# Can't create a database programmatically

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create a database through visual studios, however I can't. I get the error message: "Cannot open database "database1" requested by the login. the login failed. Login failed for user '123'" However if I manually create "database1" in SQL server studios and then try to connect to it via c# code I can connect to the database fine. I have created a user with the id 123 and password abc in server studios with every server role checkbox ticked. I am using SQL Express 2012.

```
private void sQLToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool create_db = false;
        bool create_table = false;


        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost; Database = database1; User Id = 123; Password = abc;");
        try
        {

            myConnection.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("We were able to connect to the database!", "Success!");
            create_table = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            create_db = true;
            MessageBox.Show("There is no database. We will create one.", "No Database Found.");
        }

        // For creating the database if not found
        if (create_db == true)
        {
            String str;
            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost; Database = database1; User Id = 123; Password = abc;");

            str = "CREATE DATABASE database1";

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
            try
            {
                myConn.Open();
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "Creation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                create_db = false;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    myConn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can't specify a database that doesn't exist.  If you need to create the database, don't specify an `initial catalog` nor `database` value.  After you've successfully created the database, then you can specify the database.

Comment: I am new to SQL is it as simple as removing "Database = database1;" from the connection string? I don't totally understand "after you've successfully create the database I can specify it."

Comment: Dear @Vince, Please consider using master database as your initial catalog, something like this: Database = master;

Comment: mostafa8026 thank you. I have spent 2 hours on this and it was as simple as that...

Comment: Happens because you NEVER DEBUGGED: It is obvious your error is NOT creating a database as the error happens on myConn.Open () - before submitting a command. As such, your title is wrong. If you would have used a debugger once in all that time you should have seen where the error happens and then you would have started to read the error which says it clearly.

Answer (score 2):

based on comments:
if you are attempting to create a database programmatically, you can't use a connection to an unborn database, so in this situation you must open a connection to `master` database, something like that:

```
"Server = localhost; Database = master; User Id = 123; Password = abc;"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        String str;
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;User Id = 123; Password = abc;database=master");

        str = "CREATE DATABASE database1";

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "Creation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                myConn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Please try this above code. Its working for me.Don't give database name before you create the database. Use database master for initialize the database connection.